# Powershell to determine if it is a user or a group from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, adsi

I am trying to create a workaround for Get-LocalGroupMember issue which is described here:
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2996

After reading that, I came up with this function to get all members from a local group:

```
function Get-LocalGroupMember2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
      [string]$Groupname
    )
    
    $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/$Groupname"
       $members = $group.Invoke('Members') | ForEach-Object {
           $path = ([adsi]$_).path
           Write-Host ">>> $path"
           [pscustomobject]@{
               Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
               Domain = $(Split-Path (Split-Path $path) -Leaf)
               User = $(Split-Path $path -Leaf)
           }
       }
   return $members 
}
```

Here is an example output:

```
>>> WinNT://MyDomain/TestUser
>>> WinNT://MyDomain/TestGroup

Computer   Domain   User
--------   ------   ----
NyComputer MyDomain TestUser
NyComputer MyDomain TestGroup
```

Now, I want to know if a member is a user or a group. Something like:

```
Computer   Domain   Name       Type
--------   ------   ----       ----
NyComputer MyDomain TestUser   User
NyComputer MyDomain TestGroup  Group
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight modification, you can use the `.Class` property of each member instance:

```
function Get-LocalGroupMember2 {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $Groupname
    )

    $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME/$Groupname"
    $group.Invoke('Members') | ForEach-Object {
        $member = [adsi] $_
        Write-Host ">>> $path"
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            Domain   = Split-Path (Split-Path $member.Path) -Leaf
            User     = Split-Path $member.Path -Leaf
            Class    = $member.Class
        }
    }
}
```